# how to stop form submission with express.js and node

Tags: forms, validation, node.js, express, ejs

I am validating my form with express-validator...if I have errors, what's the best way to stop the form from submitting and go back to the login page. This is what I have, which works, just looking for best way to handle this (not sure about the return statement).

```
//routes/index.js
exports.login.post = function(req, res){
  req.assert('username', 'Please enter username').notEmpty();
  req.assert('password', 'Please enter password').notEmpty();
  res.locals.errors = req.validationErrors(true);

  if ( res.locals.errors ) {
    console.log(res.locals.errors);
    var d = { title: 'Login' };
    res.render('login', { d: d });
    return;
  }

 //do login here if no errors
};
```

I also do not know how to get at original values in form template (ejs).

I tried passing req.param in, but it is empty.

The err object only has those fields with errors, so if I enter username, but leave password blank, I only get password in err object, not username...so I need req.param.username, but when I pass { q: req.param} and use <%= inspect(q) %> it is empty.

**update:** req.body gives me the original post parameters to pre-populate the form. so you need err stack and req.body stack to have a good experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do

```
app.post('/form_process', validateForm, form.handle)
function validateForm(req, res, next) {
  req.assert('username', 'Invalid Username').notEmpty().isAlpha();
  req.assert('password', 'Invalid Password').notEmpty().isAlpha();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    //res.send(errors,500);
    var original_values = {
      username: req.param('username'),
      password: req.param('password')
    }
    res.render('login', { errorMsg: errors, original: original_values, title: "Login error" })
    return;
  }
  else next()
}
```

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't read that you want to pass original values. Updated the answer

Comment: this answer is selected answer. I didn't reject it.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest doing is using something like [flashify](https://npmjs.org/package/flashify) to set a flash notification and redirect the request back to the view.

So you can do something like:

```
if ( res.locals.errors ) 
{
  res.flash('error','bad username/password');
  req.session.formData = req.body;
  res.redirect('back');
}
```

Then inside the view, you just check if `flash.error` exists, and output the message if it does, then: `<%= flash.error %>` :)

Comment: still need the original request object though to pre-populate the form when an error is encountered.

Comment: You can do that as well. `req.session.formData = req.body` before the `res.redirect`